# Validate at least 1 of a set of args is present in Kotlin class constructor

Tags: validation, kotlin, constructor

### **Scenario**

I need to create a Kotlin class that can receive up to 4 arguments for its constructor, but only requires at least 1 out of a set of 3 (the fourth being entirely optional). To illustrate:

```kotlin
class Pie {

// Completely optional, the constructor should use it if present, otherwise it may be null.
    var topping: String?   

// Of these three [fillingA, fillingB, fillingC] 1 or more must be present.
    var fillingA: String?   
    var fillingB: String?  
    var fillingC: String?
}
```

### **Thoughts**

I've attempted to use Kotlin `init{}` blocks for validation, or telescoping constructors, but it gets ugly fast and I've yet to solve the issue. I have not found anything in the [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org) docs on primary/secondary constructors that is more elegant, though. My preference would be to find something similar to the `@Size` or `@NotNull` annotations, but I have failed to locate anything close.

**It is important to note that I am using this class as a model for an API response.**

### **Question**

What is the most concise way to validate that a Kotlin class has at least 1 of a set of arguments passed to its constructor?

Comment: Maybe aggregate fillings into an array or a map? That way you can just check if it's not empty.

Comment: Do you need to validate at compile time?

Comment: Since I am mapping an API response to it, no. Good question @Tenfour04

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your idea, @Pawel. Would you mind posting an example? Do you mean to receive an array, or use an init block to aggregate and then check size?

Comment: The problem here is that "Pie" is clearly an analogy for the class you're trying to implement, which makes it hard for us to offer alternative suggestions. For example, if you really wanted a pie, I would suggest making the fillings a list, and simply throw exceptions if the list is < 1 or  > 3 on initialization.

However, I am not sure if that suites your use case.

Comment: Obviously the code here is an analogy, because the actual class is proprietary. It is still accurate to the actual class, however. I was not asking for someone else to write my code for me. If you look at the bolded question, it is specific to validating the args passed to the constructor. I was just curious about an interesting scenario that I encountered. There is no 'problem' here @Clay07g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are this fillings interchangeable? You could assume that fillingA is always required and the other ones are optional, something like this:

```
class Pie constructor(
    val fillingA: String,
    val fillingB: String? = null,
    val fillingC: String? = null,
    val topping: String? = null
){...}
```

Comment: That's clever, and other than @Pawel's idea above, the only way I can currently find to address the scenario in the case that I presented above. I actually think I could leave every one of the parameters nullable and write the validation into the mapper that is responding to the api call, for my use specifically, but this gave me the nudge in that direciton. Thanks for the idea!